# ERGODOX - where is the underscore character in ORYX?

Tags: keyboard

I cannot find any mention of the underscore character in https://configure.ergodox-ez.com/

This is specific to the ergodox keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many keys are not named in the current version of this tool.  You have to search through the list manually if you don't have a key already setup, which seems to be the situation I was in.  Now I have a "_" character.

Answer (score 0):

you should also get to it when typing SHIFT-'-' in the configurator - that's probably the easiest way

When you do that it shows as "Shifted punctuation _" in the dialogue box.

[image]